# Alt+Space shows up as Â instead of a blank space HTML

Tags: html, ascii, ascii-art

I have a section of code.

`########<br># BANK #<br>#   _  #<br>#  | | #`

this uses the Alt+Space instead of a normal space because normal spaces disapear.

So the building should look like this

########
  # BANK #
  #     _     #
  #    | |     #

But instead it looks like this

[image] - image because some reason stack overflow formats it correctly...

So how come when I do Alt+Space it shows up as a space in my editor (Textastic) but in the browser as a Â?

And I don't want to use `&nbsp;` because its easier to make ASCII art using Alt+Space.

Comment: What is your document's encoding?

Comment: And you specified that in the document head?

Comment: Ok i tried it and it worked

Comment: I couldn't find a relevant question to close this question as a duplicate of, but I did find [this](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
```

fixed it

credit to [Daedalus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785241/daedalus)!

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: ^^^^ Yeah that, plus it seems kinda rude to take someone else's solution and pass it off as your own answer to the very thread you started.

Comment: @JanAagaardMeier: I respectfully disagree. Adding *exactly this* into the question would make it Not A Question. Also, since it is a valid (and apparently correct) solution, no reason for a downvote. The OP can leave this as an answer and even mark it as "Accepted". If he doesn't wish to take credit for it, he can always convert it into a Community Wiki answer.